# Tensorflow - Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate

Tags: tensorflow

Hi I know this is a frequent problem that one encounters and most solutions are to allow growth of the GPU using this code:

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
sess = tf.Session(config = config)
```

I included this code in the train.py file and batch size is only 1 but I still get the same error. I ran `nvidia-smi` and this is my output:

```
    +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 442.19       Driver Version: 442.19       CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1060   WDDM  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   82C    P2    65W /  N/A |   5069MiB /  6144MiB |     99%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0       796      C   ...cal\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe N/A      |
```

Any help on what is happening to cause the OOM error over and over again. Training is still going but very slow.

Comment: Could you provide your code?